# problem in configuring dataproc cluster from GCP Console since Friday (1 february 2024)

Tags: google-cloud-platform, cluster-computing, google-cloud-dataproc

He everybody,
when trying to choose the Dataproc cluster machine type from GCP Console, It seems that the system isn't able to get and display the RAM dimension in Gb of each suggested solution. When I try to create the cluster anyway, the system show me an error message.
Can someone help me?
Thanks so much.
[RAM dimension isn't displayed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/67Rw7.jpg)
[the error returned when launching the cluster creation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdVqg.jpg)

I tryed to change the browser from Chrome to Microsoft Edge.
I cleand the browser cache.